# Change The Second page Margin for .pdf (Created via WickedPDF)

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, wicked-gem

I would like to change the top margins ONLY for the second page of an auto-generated .pdf. It is created via the WickedPDF gem (https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf). The auto-generated pdfs all differ in length and the second page content is not always the same. By the way, I didn't find the following solution helpful: [WickedPDF different margin settings for first page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27010261/wickedpdf-different-margin-settings-for-first-page).